# Groupby dataframe to count values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to groupby and get the count per value.

```
date         Severity          
01-12-22      Sev1             
05-12-22      Sev5             
22-12-22      Sev1             
01-01-23      Sev4             
21-01-23      sev4             
30-01-23      sev3
```

And I want to count each Severity by month-year

```
date         Sev1  Sev2  Sev3  Sev4 Sev5          
12-22          2    0     0     0     1                         
01-23          0    0     1     2     0
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['date'].str[-5:], df['Severity'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) after normalizing the dates:

```
out = pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('M'),
                  df['Severity'])
```

Output:

```
Severity  Sev1  Sev4  Sev5  sev3  sev4
date                                  
2022-12      2     0     1     0     0
2023-01      0     1     0     1     1
```

Or as strings:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['date'].str.extract('(\d{2}-\d{2})$', expand=False),
                  df['Severity'])
```

Output:

```
Severity  Sev1  Sev4  Sev5  sev3  sev4
date                                  
01-23        0     1     0     1     1
12-22        2     0     1     0     0
```